# Theano only using 40% of my GPU

Tags: python, gpu, deep-learning, theano, theano-cuda

I am starting to get into deep learning and I am trying out the example from [Chapter 6 on neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html). Theano is telling me, that it is using my GPU (a GTX 780). However, the GPU usage hovers only at around 40~50% and the clockspeed is only at ~800 MHz (normal Boost clock in games is ~1100 MHz).

Is this normal? Or is something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. Actually, 40~50% should be considered high usage. Some operations like vector concatenation are performed on CPU. The GPU has to wait these operations to be completed before using the results as input. Besides, the overhead can be caused by loading data from memory.

So people commonly run 2~3 programs on the same GPU to take full advantage of it.